# global vs $GLOBALS

Tags: php

I have this code

```
/// Example 1
$str = "Simple text";
$a = function()
{
    global $str;
    $str = "edited";
};
$a();
echo $str."\n"; /// edited

/// Example 2
$str = "Simple text";
$a = function()
{
    $GLOBALS["str"] = "edited";
};
$a();
echo $str."\n"; /// edited

/// Example 3
$str = "Simple text";
$temp = "";
$a = function()
{
    $GLOBALS["temp"] = &$GLOBALS["str"];
};
$a();
echo "[".$str."] [".$temp."]\n"; /// [Simple text] [Simple text]

/// Example 4
$str = "Simple text";
$temp = "";
$a = function()
{
    global $str, $temp;
    $temp = &$str;
};
$a();
echo "[".$str."] [".$temp."]\n"; /// [Simple text] []
```

The first example displays as well as the expected change in the value of the second example of the same thing ... it would seem there is no difference, go ahead! In the third example, the function we make a hard link to superglobal array displays as expected the same word, and now look at a fourth example, and ... I'm not in a stupor, he links and displays only the variable `$str`, and the variable `$temp` reserves empty, why?

Comment: http://php.net/variables.scope

Comment: You should really not use `global` or the superglobal `$GLOBALS`, if you look into the source code you're not familiar with, you'll just keep asking yourself "Where does that variable come from?" it's important to know where it comes from, passing it as argument and return it back is the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is greatly explained in docs: http://php.net/variables.scope and http://php.net/manual/language.references.spot.php

```
global $a;
```

Is a shortcut to:

```
$a = &$GLOBALS['a'];
```

So lets expand your last example:

```
$a = function()
{
    $str = &$GLOBALS['str'];
    $temp = &$GLOBALS['temp'];
    $temp = &$str;  // okay, but $temp is still the local variable 
};
```

I think everything works as expected

Comment: Because in this function `$temp` is local. It is only the reference to global `$temp`. And also, unsetting the local `$temp` wont affect the global one. The real value in function scope can be accessed this way `$GLOBALS['temp']`.Updated the answer, added another link to docs.